# What are my rights when someone else uses a voucher issued to me?

Tags: theft, compensation, identity-theft

I was issued a £360 voucher from Easyjet after my suitcases didn't arrive for four days after a flight I took. The voucher was sent to me via email in direct response to a protracted claim I had made.

When I called Easyjet to redeem the voucher, I was informed that the credit had already been used. Upon further investigation, it emerged that someone else had called Easyjet, successfully answered the security questions they posed, and spent the credit.

Here's another important detail: The ticket was originally booked by someone else - we'll call them Mr Bob - who changed the name and transferred the ticket to me. Easyjet Customer Services claim that the person who called and used my voucher presented themselves as Mr Bob.

Assuming that it was the person who had originally made the booking who had used my voucher:

1. As the original purchaser of the ticket, does Mr Bob have any right to a voucher issued to reimburse me for expenses I (the traveller) incurred as a result of my missing suitcases?
2. Assuming that Mr Bob had no right to use the voucher,
   Do I have any legal claim against:

- Easyjet to reimburse me for the voucher, since they authorized a fraudulent use of my credit to someone else of a different name?
- Mr Bob for using a voucher issued to me, thus causing me the loss of my credit?

---

For what it's worth, I live in the UK.

Comment: Your question assumes that Bob does not have rights to the voucher as the purchaser of the ticket. This may be incorrect.

Comment: @user71659 - I intended that to be a part of my query. I've amended the question to reflect that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is Mr. Bob your employer, and did he purchase your ticket for business travel? (*this would seem to also be an important detail...*)

Comment: Mr Bob is a friend, and he purchased the ticket for personal use. I purchased the ticket off him when his plans changed and he decided not to take the flight.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  (Not a very good friend apparently... ) You might consider editing the question to reflect this, because I wasn't even aware that you could sell a ticket to another.  Most are non-transferable.

Comment: There was a newspaper story about a guy who bought a very expensive cruise for himself and his fiancé. Then they split up. He couldn't get his money back, didn't want to travel alone, so he advertised and found a lady with the same name who joined him on a free cruise.